# Getting a string input with make command to use as a main argument in C program

Tags: c, makefile

I'm having trouble using makefile commands to get a user input. What I need is to ask the user the name of TXT file (which is located in ./data/), then to use the path to this file as an argument for my main C program.

Make code :

```
launch-app-conway: app-conway
  @read -p "Enter file name: " FILENAME
  FILEPATH = "./data/"
  FILEPATH += FILENAME
  ./main-program FILEPATH
```

It outputs "FILEPATH : command not found".

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Try `./main-program $FILEPATH`

Comment: I still get "FILEPATH : command not found" then "make *** error 127"

Comment: Try to remove these lines `FILEPATH = "./data/"
  FILEPATH += FILENAME` and just enter the path with './data/' when asked. And change the last line to `./main-program $(FILEPATH)`. What do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a lot of issues here.  First, you're not using variables at all.  The value `FILENAME` is just a text string, a literal word `FILENAME`.  It's not a variable reference.

Second, you seem to be trying to use make variable assignment etc. in your makefile recipe.  A makefile recipe (the parts indented by TAB characters) are passed to the shell and you have to use shell syntax (there is no `+=` assignment in the shell for example).

Third, every logical line in a makefile recipe is passed to a different shell, and variable assignments made in a shell are lost when the shell exits, so even if the variable references were correct and you were using correct shell syntax to construct the variable `FILEPATH`, it would be empty because it was constructed in a different shell.

You can do what you want using this:

```
launch-app-conway: app-conway
        @read -p "Enter file name: " FILENAME; \
        ./main-program "./data/$$FILENAME"
```

However, note that if you try to run this makefile with `-j` it may not work properly since your recipe might not have access to stdin.

Answer (score 1):

Each line of a recipe spawns a new shell.  Therefore, if you set a variable in line 1, then that variable will be forgotten before line line2.  You can concatinate the lines using `\`  As well, you seem to be missing dollar signs (not sure which shell you're using), but typically, a single dollar sign in a recpipe refers to a make variable, and a double is used for shell variables.

What you want is something like:

```
launch-app-conway: app-conway
    @read -p "Enter file name: " FILENAME; \
    FILEPATH="./data/$$FILENAME"; \
    echo $$FILEPATH
```

(Note: if you want to cut and paste from here, remember that SI converts tabs to spaces, and Makefiles require spaces).

Comment: I think you meant to say "Makefile requires tabs", not "spaces"